# Segmentation fault in EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new() when using OpenSSL in C

Tags: c, openssl, evp-cipher

I am a total beginner with the OpenSSL Library in C but was working on a code to encrypt using the libraries while taking a pass phrase as input and generating the salt,IV and key from the pass phrase. This is what I have tried till now:

```
int encrypt(unsigned char *plaintext, int plaintext_len, unsigned char *ciphertext)
{
char *passphrase;
printf("\nEnter a Pass Phrase:");
scanf("%s",passphrase);

ERR_load_crypto_strings();
OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
OPENSSL_config(NULL);

EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx;
const EVP_CIPHER *cipher;
const EVP_MD *dgst = NULL;
unsigned char key[EVP_MAX_KEY_LENGTH], iv[EVP_MAX_IV_LENGTH];
const char *salt;

int len;

int ciphertext_len;

/* Create and initialise the context */
if(!(ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new())) //This line causes the error
    handleErrors();
cipher = EVP_get_cipherbyname("aes-256-cbc");
if(!cipher) { fprintf(stderr, "no such cipher\n"); return -1; }
dgst=EVP_get_digestbyname("md5");
if(!dgst) { fprintf(stderr, "no such digest\n"); return -1; }

if(!EVP_BytesToKey(cipher, dgst, salt, (unsigned char *) passphrase, strlen(passphrase), 1, key, iv))
{
    fprintf(stderr, "EVP_BytesToKey failed\n");
    return -1;
}

/* Initialise the encryption operation. IMPORTANT - ensure you use a key
* and IV size appropriate for your cipher
* In this example we are using 256 bit AES (i.e. a 256 bit key). The
* IV size for *most* modes is the same as the block size. For AES this
* is 128 bits */
if(1 != EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), NULL, key, iv))
handleErrors();

/* Provide the message to be encrypted, and obtain the encrypted output.
* EVP_EncryptUpdate can be called multiple times if necessary
*/
if(1 != EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, ciphertext, &len, plaintext, plaintext_len))
handleErrors();
ciphertext_len = len;

/* Finalise the encryption. Further ciphertext bytes may be written at
* this stage.
*/
if(1 != EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(ctx, ciphertext + len, &len)) handleErrors();
ciphertext_len += len;

/* Clean up */
EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
EVP_cleanup();
ERR_free_strings();

return ciphertext_len;
}
```

I tried this out but kept getting a segmentation fault. I tried to debug and found out that the EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new() was the one cussing it. I am at my wits end right now trying to debug it and could really appreciate some help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is incorrect:

```
char *passphrase;
printf("\nEnter a Pass Phrase:");
scanf("%s",passphrase);
```

`char *pasphrase` is just a pointer point to unknown location.

Change this to:

```
char passphrase[2048];
printf("\nEnter a Pass Phrase:");
scanf("%s", passphrase);
```